# Java Load File to pass to other class

Tags: java, file-io

What is the best way to load a file into a java application to be passed to another class?

Currently I am using JFileChooser to select a source file (C, C++, Java) which is then passed to an executable called src2srcml. My code runs the src2srcml tool which takes the source file and converts it to an XML which is then stored in my workspace (eclipse). I then want to take that XML file and pass it over to another class to be analysed. As you can see below I am currently trying the getResources method. It can find the file fine but I don't actually know how to pass it to the class UnitXMLReader. GetResources returns a URL to the file but the other class needs the filepath. Is there a better way to find the file?

```
JButton btnRunSourceCode = new JButton("Run Source Code");
    btnRunSourceCode.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            //------Check for loaded file ----//
            if(filePath == null){
                textArea.setText("Please Load a source file (C, C++, Java)");                   
            }
            else{
                try{
                    int c;
                    textArea.setText("Converting Source Code to XML");
                    String workspace = System.getProperty("user.dir");
                    String classPath = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
                    String[] commands = {"/bin/bash", "-c", "cd " + workspace + " && ./src2srcml --position " + selectedFile.getName() + " -o " + classPath + "/xmlParseGUI/targetFile.xml"};

                    Process src2XML = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands);
                    InputStream in1 = src2XML.getErrorStream();
                    InputStream in2 = src2XML.getInputStream();
                    while ((c = in1.read()) != -1 || (c = in2.read()) != -1) {
                        System.out.print((char)c);
                        }
                    src2XML.waitFor();
                    }

                catch(Exception exc){/*src2srcml Fail*/}
            }

            ParallelXMlGUI c = new ParallelXMlGUI();
            Class<? extends ParallelXMlGUI> cls = c.getClass();

            // finds resource relative to the class location
            URL url = cls.getResource("targetFile.xml");
            //UnitXMLReader.ChosenFile = filePath;
            //UnitXMLReader.main(null);
            System.out.println("Value = " + url);
```

Comment: File file = new File(filePath);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
File file = new File(classPath + "/xmlParseGUI/targetFile.xml);
```

Java has a file class for handling files.  Try creating a new File object that points to that file. Then pass the new File object.

Or you could try relative path:

```
File file = new File("/smlParseGUI/targetFile.xml");
```

A couple File methods:

```
file.getPath();
file.getString();
```